Forward chaining LIFO
For forward chaining (LIFO) it was mentioned that

Depth strategy: Newly activated rules are placed above all rules of
the  same salience : for example if fact-a activates rule-1 and rule-2
and  fact-b activates rule-3 and rule-4, then if fact-a is asserted
before fact b, rule-3 and rule-4 will be above rule-1 and rule-2 on
the agenda.  However the position of rule3 relative to rule-4 will be
arbitrary

so if I have the following facts and rules
(deffacts my_facts
(B)
(C))

(defrule r1
(B)(D)(E)=> (assert (F)))

(defrule r2
(C)(D) => (assert (A)))

(defrule r3
(C)(F)=>(assert (A)))

(defrule r4
(B) => (assert (X)))

(defrule r5
(D) => (assert (D)))

(defrule r6
(X)(A) => (assert(H))
(printout t 'H' is reached crlf)
(halt))

(defrule r7
(C)
=> (assert (D)))

(defrule r8
(X)
(C)
=> (assert (A)))

(defrule r9
(X)
(B)
=> (assert (D)))

then
(reset)
(watch all)
(run)

The idea is that, it seems that r2 is always fired before r5, but I thought that:
the position of rule-2 relative to rule-5 will be arbitrary, so why do we have R2 fired before R5 every time ?
this is the image which represents the case :


It's arbitrary as in "based on or determined by individual preference or convenience," not as in "existing or coming about seemingly at random." In the Basic Programming Guide at the beginning of section 5.3, Conflict Resolution Strategies, it's mentioned that arbitrary as used does not mean random.

If a rule is activated (along with several other rules) by the same
assertion or retraction of a fact, and steps a and b are unable to
specify an ordering, then the rule is arbitrarily (not randomly)
ordered in relation to the other rules with which it was activated.
Note, in this respect, the order in which rules are defined has an
arbitrary effect on conflict resolution (which is highly dependent
upon the current underlying implementation of rules). Do not depend
upon this arbitrary ordering for the proper execution of your rules.


sorry , I didn't get the idea why 2 is always been chosen over 5 every time

Rule 2 and rule 5 are both activated by the assertion of fact D. The matching algorithm is deterministic, so it's going to process the assertion of facts the same way every time. In this case, the activation of rule 5 occurs first followed by the activation of rule 2.  Since rule 2 was activated last, it fires before rule 5 because of the depth strategy.

and is there a reason for the activation for rule5 occurs first ?

Pattern (D) is shared by rules 1, 2, and 5. The linked list from pattern (D) to the rules it affects is constructed by appending affected rules to the beginning of the list. This results in a linked list of 5, 2, and 1. Thus when the fact (D) is asserted, rule 5 is activated before rule 2 because it occurs before rule 2 in the linked list.

sorry for that, but can you explain more (or give me a resource on that), why D occurs before in the linked list ?

Here's a link to the rete algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm. The answer to your question, however, is because it was coded that way. If you create a linked list and then add items to it, the items could be added at the beginning, the end, or inserted somewhere in the middle of the list.  Each one of these methods would produce different output if the list was printed in sequential order. If the ordering of the list was not important, most people would just add new items to the beginning since that is the simplest thing to do.
